# How to automatically return to Flash perspective after debugging in Flash Builder 4

Tags: eclipse, flex4, flash-builder

Flash Builder 4 knows how to automatically switch on the Debug perspective when the user starts debugging, but when the debugging session is over (e.g. terminated) it remains in the debug perspective. Can it be configured to automatically return to the development perspective when the debugger is detached / process is terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only options you get involve actual modes. The three modes for FlashBuilder are Debug, Run, and Profile, and each triggers the perspective check. If you select any of these actions, you can associate it with a perspective. But unless there's a plugin I don't know about, you can't associate a perspective without a mode trigger.

Comment: I was going to suggest using the keyboard shortcut keys, but there are none for perspectives...

Comment: When I saw this question was answered I got excited, but unfortunately it's not the answer I was hoping for. :(  I really wish Adobe (Eclipse?) would do something about this, it seems like something minor but it makes me (and everyone else I know that uses FB) crazy.

Answer (score 5):

I created a plugin which does this:

http://www.richinternet.de/blog/index.cfm?entry=7FC75E95-E7BA-2BC1-F0500960913E75EF

Dirk.

Comment: Thanks, works a charm! :)  For those that have already changed the Eclipse preference to never switch perspectives, you can revert that setting by going to Preferences -> Run/Debug in Eclipse